# http.get causes Japanese text to get jumbled

Tags: flutter, http, encoding, get

I am using following code to get data from a server that has Japanese text.

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      });
```

I get the data correctly but all the Japanese text does not look correct. They look like

```
æ±äº¬éƒ½ä¸­å¤®åŒºæ—¥æœ¬æ©‹å®¤ç”º3-3-9
```

When I use "Postman" to check the data, it is displaying Japanese text correctly.

How do I get around this issue?

I have the same problem when I put the values.

I use;

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'authorization': basicAuth,
};

final msg = jsonEncode(data);

final response = await http.put(
  url,
  headers: headers,
  body: msg,
);
```

The data does not seems to encode correctly, when they are in Japanese.
Can someone provide some help on this ?

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. `äº¬éƒ½ä¸­å¤®åŒºæ—¥æœ¬æ©‹å®¤ç”º3-3-9` looks like `'京都中央区日本橋室町3-3-9'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')`.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I have similar problem with http.put. Maybe there is a header setting or http.put setting I have to do?